# Background property not applying

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

Working on an XAML window:

Here is my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding myStuff}" SelectedItem="{mySelectedStuff}" Background="Red" Foreground="Green" />
```

My binding works fine, the foreground property applies but the background property doees not apply.
Whatever value I set, it stays Grey.

Is there anything I might have forgotten?

On other pages, background works fine. I do not manage to determine what is different on this particular page.

This style applies:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" >
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
</Style>
```

It does not work better if I set the background property into the style rather than into the control.

EDIT:
problem solved.
My style posted was conflicting with another style. If I remove my custom style, it works fine.

Well useless post in the end.
Thx anyway for your kind assistance.

Comment: As you will understand, we cannot reproduce this, so we cannot help you (for now). Copy your entire solution and (in the copy) remove everything that is not relevant. Then remove even more, until the problem goes away or there is nothing left but the relevant parts. If the problem goes away, it was in the last thing you removed. If it does not go away, post the minimal repro you have left.

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox has IsEnable="False" background will stay gray.